# In mysql, can I count how many rows satisfy some condition, if not then exit the count?

Tags: mysql

Basically I store data in MySql 5.5. I use qt to connect to mysql. I want to compare two columns, if col1 is greater than col2, the count continues, but when col1 is less than col2, count finishes and exits. So this is to count how many rows under some condition at the beginning of column. Is it possible in mysql?

An example:

Col1 Col2

2    1

2    3

2    1

The count I need should return 1, because the first row meets the condition of Col1 > Col2, but the second row doesn't. Whenever the condition is not meet, counting exits no matter if following rows meet the condition or not.

Comment: What king of conditions do you wanna impose?

Comment: Like i said, col1 > col2

Comment: If you can provide information as to the table structure and preferably what you've tried already / sample data then I'm sure you'll get a better answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a bit ugly, but will do the job.  It'll need adjusting depending on any ORDER etc you would like to apply to `someTable` but the principle is sound.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
    SELECT
        @multiplier:=@multiplier*IF(t.`col1`<t.`col2`,0,1) AS counter
    FROM `someTable` t, (SELECT @multiplier := 1) v
    HAVING counter = 1
) scanQuery
```

The @multiplier variable will keep multiplying itself by 1.  When it encounters a row where `col1 < col2` it multiplies by 0.  It will then continue multiplying 0 x 1.  The outer query then just sums them up.

It's not ideal, but would suffice.  This could be expanded to allow you to get those rows before the break by doing the following

```
SELECT 
    `someTable`.*
FROM `someTable`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        `someTable`.`PrimaryKeyField`
        @multiplier:=@multiplier*IF(`col1`<`col2`,0,1) AS counter
    FROM `someTable` t, (SELECT @multiplier := 1) v
    HAVING counter = 1
) t
ON scanQuery.`PrimaryKeyField` = `someTable`.`PrimaryKeyField`
```

Or possibly simply

```
    SELECT
        `someTable`.*
        @multiplier:=@multiplier*IF(`col1`<`col2`,0,1) AS counter
    FROM `someTable` t, (SELECT @multiplier := 1) v
    HAVING counter = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. This is brilliant! Another question, maybe not related to this problem: is it better I do this kind of implementation under mysql, or should I better done it in Something like C++? Since Im making the connection in Qt, and using Qt to get my data, so now I also write mysql command under Qt. I guess my option one is your solution, which is nice, another solution is to take those two columns to memory and use C language to get this kind of counting, and return the result back to database. Which one is more efficient? Thank you for the help.

Comment: It's hard to really say catagorically without spending time checking what kinda of data is involved (volume/structure).  If you have a key on `(col1,col2)` together then the subquery here should be pretty fast though, and so I would expect of the two it would be faster to have MySQL prune results than transport the whole dataset.

Comment: Just as a final note - I've no experience with C++ nor with Qt, only with MySQL in high-volume environments.  Any specific advice as to which is more efficient is beyond what can be done in a simple Q+A as it depends as noted on data volume/structure and intended usage.  Also it would probably be better answered by someone with experience in the other fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   table
WHERE  col1 > col2
```

It's a little difficult to understand what you're after, but `COUNT(*)` will return the number of rows matched by your condition, if that's your desire. If it's not, can you maybe be more specific or show example(s) of what you're going for? I will do my best to correct my answer depending on additional details.

Comment: If col1 < col2, i want the counting exit.

Comment: @Sean: SQL doesn't work like an iterator that you can `break`/`return` from unless you get in to stored procedures or functions. However, you can sort the column(s) and select only rows UP TO a specific condition. But it's still not entirely clear what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using SQL for this; any answer you get will be chock full of comprimise and if (for example) the result set from your intial query comes back in a different order (due to an index being created or changed), then they will fail.

SQL is designed for "set based" logic - and you really are after procedural logic. If you have to do this, then

1) Use a cursor

2) Use an order by statement

3) Cross fingers

Comment: Im using Qt to connect to mysql and save data. Now I have data in mysql. I know it is easy to do this job in C++/Qt, but since all my data is in database, I thought it would be the most efficient for me to handle data also in database. If I get data from daatabase to memory and do the math under Qt, and put the result back to database, will it consume more time?